# Stuck in a loop in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access I'm trying to get a sub-population of my database, all rows with the event on the specified date.

The table currently has 2500 rows and about 20-30 have the event/date combination.

When I execute this code I get stuck in a loop that lasts longer then a minute, after which I just stop it:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from oper  where oDate =" & Format(Me.txtDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"))

testtxt= ""
rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF
    testtxt = testtxt & rs!OpID & vbCrLf
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: `rs = testtxt & rs!OpID & vbCrLf` is an error. Surely your code looks different on this line?

Comment: corrected. I'm just trying to write all the ids for to test the recordset. First line looks ok as I get the correct number of records through rs.RecordCount

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint in you code and step trough line-by-line? Because frankly, these few lines cannot run forever.

Comment: Unrelated, but `mm/dd/yyyy` is not a sensible date format (for a technical representation of a date anyway). Try to get into the habit of using the unambiguous form `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Comment: Could this process use a lot of memory? I moved from one compouter to the other and it works normally. Though I find it strange that 20 recordsets would use all the memory on an old comp. the rest of things work normally on both.

Comment: No, memory can hardly be the problem. 2500 rows are *nothing*. even 250,000 are not a lot. As I said. Set a breakpoint, step through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to close your recordset after the loop and then free the memory (set recordset to nothing).

Did you try to do the same operation in a smaller DB? The environment may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what actually causes your issue, I suggest you work with [QueryDef objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845129%28v=office.15%29.aspx), because they support typed parameters.

Here's a suggested change to your code.

```
Function OperByDate(dt As Date) As DAO.Recordset
    With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS dt DateTime;" & vbNewLine & _
        "SELECT * FROM oper WHERE oDate >= [dt] AND oDate < [dt] + 1;")

        .Parameters!dt = Fix(dt)
        Set OperByDate = .OpenRecordset(dbOpenForwardOnly)
    End With
End Function
```

and

```
Sub Test()
    Dim testtxt As String

    With OperByDate(Me.txtDate)
        Do Until .EOF
            testtxt = testtxt & !OpID & vbCrLf
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    Debug.Print testtxt
End Sub
```